# Golang copy elements of object to slice

Tags: arrays, go, slice

Is there any better way to apply a function to fields of an object and then copy the result to a new slice? By better I mean having a better performance than a for loop.

```
var tmp []string
for _, value := range some_object.some_field {
    tmp = append(tmp, do_something(value))
}
```

Something like:

```
tmp := map_copy(do_something(some_object.some_field))
```

With the resulting slice being:

```
tmp[0] = do_something(some_object.some_value[0])
tmp[1] = do_something(some_object.some_value[1])
tmp[2] = do_something(some_object.some_value[2])
....
```

Comment: `map_copy` would just be a function containing your for loop. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I could just write it myself. It was more directed at the performance aspect. Maybe there is some fancy go internal i don't know which handles this better than a for loop. Sorry if unclear.

Comment: Not entirely related to this specific question, but there are a bunch of slice tricks on the wiki that expose some simple optimizations, such as append using ellipsis. Read here https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only performance increase you could add is allocating the correct slice capacity ahead of time.

You can still add values with append by starting with a 0 length slice:

```
tmp := make([]string, 0, len(some_object.some_field))
for _, value := range some_object.some_field {
    tmp = append(tmp, do_something(value))
}
```

Or by indexing the slices directly:

```
tmp := make([]string, len(some_object.some_field))
for i := range some_object.some_field {
    tmp[i] = do_something(some_object.some_field[i])
}
```